# Sorting columns is very slow in Access after moving back-end to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I used the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access tool to move a database to SQL Server and keep Access as the front end. Everything went pretty smoothly and the data looks right, reports are working well, etc. I'm just having one problem that is making it basically unusable.

When I open a table in Access and try to sort a column it is very very slow. When I click the column and choose an option (like Sort A-Z for example) it will will say "Calculating..." in the bottom left for about a minute before it will actually sort the column.

Is there any way to speed this up? Did I do something in the migration that might have caused this? It wasn't having any issues with this before.

Comment: You could use the SQL-Server Profiler to see what kind of command Access sends to the DB when you sort. This might give you a hint on what's going on and whether refactoring things or adding an index would help. Is the column you are sorting on a calculated column? Note: VBA functions in a query are executed by access. Transforming such a query either into a pass-through query (i.e., into SQL-Server dialect) or into a SQL view could help in such a case.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is not a calculated column. Do you have any good links you could provide for making pass-through queries or sql views? I've been trying to look for documentation on implementing those solutions and I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: [Create a pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42). [SQL View – A complete introduction and walk-through](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-view-a-complete-introduction-and-walk-through/). You can then link the view as a table into Access. In both cases you will have to write the query in the SQL-Server [TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) dialect.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks! I'll check that out and hopefully it will help me solve my issue.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not normal behavior, so investigating what actually happens would be a good idea, perhaps better than starting to build workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info about the table (i.e. its size, indexes and network speed) its hard to say for sure why you are seeing this delay, but there are some steps you can take to narrow down the source of the delay.

In SQL Server Management Studio, create a query that sorts that same column in the table.  (i.e. `Select * from Tablename ORDER BY Columnname;`).

If this runs quickly, then you can be pretty sure the table is fine along with its indexes, and you need to look at the network speed between your computer and the SQL server.  If it runs slowly, then the issue is with the table, its indexes or maybe even the SQL server is under powered.